# Ether.js BigNumber overflow when I use a contract with wei

Tags: metamask, javascript, ethers.js

I made a page where you can enter an amount of token and it gets swapped to another token.
It works until I use a number **above *999***. My smartcontract gets wei, so I have to transform the normal number to wei with the function below.

```
const toWei = amount => {
    return amount * Math.pow(10, 18)
}
```

I get huge numbers out and I get this error

```
Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="2e+21", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)
```

What can I do that this does not appear and is best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `"2e+21"` is not valid for the `BigNumber` class.

JavaScript uses IEEE 754 numbers, which means any value above around `0.009` would suffer precision loss, and Ethereum is quite picky about numbers not being approximate.

You should use strings for large values, or use the convenience functions provided for converting units, such as `ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")` which handles string values.

Here is more info on why you need Big Number: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--notes-safenumbers

Comment: This worked tyvm
I have checked the documentation, but I used formatUnit/formatEther instead of parseEther